# ¿Cómo definir el tamaño de un struct mediante entrada por teclado en c++?

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando un programa donde se requiere que el struct tenga n tamaño. Estoy un poco confundido sobre cómo asignarle el tamaño al struct mediante entrada por teclado.

Gracias.

```
cout<<"Digite la opción: ";
    cin>>op;
    if(op==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        int n;
        cout<<"Digite la cantidad de libros que desea almacenar: ";
        cin>>n;
        n2 = n;
        objetos *o = new objetos[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"LIBRO "<<i+1<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cout<<"Digite el número de referencia del libro: ";
            getline(cin,o[i].num_ref);
            cout<<"Digite el título: ";
            getline(cin,o[i].titulo);
            cout<<"Digite el autor: ";
            getline(cin,o[i].autor);
            cout<<"Digite la editorial: ";
            getline(cin,o[i].editorial);
            o[i].tipo = "Libro";
            cout<<"Digite el número de edición: ";
            getline(cin,o[i].num_edi);
            cout<<"Digite el año de publicación: ";
            getline(cin,o[i].annio);
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            j++;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    if(op==2)
    {
        cout<<"Digite la cantidad de revistas que desea almacenar: ";
        cin>>n;
    }

    if(op==3)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<o[0].tipo<<endl;
        /*for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
        {
            cout<<o[i].tipo<<" "<<i+1<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].num_ref<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].titulo<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].autor<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].editorial<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].tipo<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].num_edi<<endl;
            cout<<o[i].annio<<endl<<endl;

        }*/ 
    }
```

Pues lo que he probado es hacerlo por apuntadores. Antes lo tenía con un switch, pero saltaba de una vez al siguiente case y daba un error. Así que decidí dejarlo por ahora con if. Como se puede observar al crear el apuntador éste se creará sólo para el primer if. Y necesito que también esté en el tercer if, ya que yo estoy creando un nuevo apuntador y pues ese apuntador no tiene información alguna. Así que ese for no muestra nada. xD

Comment: Agrega el código que estas probando @Sercroft1.

Comment: Ya coloqué el código.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a un `vector<T>`?

Comment: Sí, el que le dal el tamaño al struct. Ese es el que necesito definir por medio de entrada por teclado. struct hola{...}h[...];

Comment: PD: Para evitar que los `case` de un `switch` colapsen necesitas agregar le statement `break` después de cada `case`

Comment: Los tenía, pero daba igualmente el error... La verdad me dejó patidifuso.

Comment: [Error] jump to case label [-fpermissive]  - [Error] crosses initialization of 'prueba* p'

Comment: Entiendo que este método está en algún tipo de loop donde quieres que la operación anterior quede almacenada. Es decir, en la primera iteración se inicializa el `struct` de objetos con la operación `1` y en el siguiente, si se accede a la operación `3`, el `struct` ya está inicializado (?.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106621/discussion-between-vroxa-and-sercroft1).

Comment: El struct lo inicialice al inicio del programa, antes del int main(). Ya en la operación 1 lo que hago es crear el apuntador para asignarle el tamaño al struct desde ahí, aunque no sé si está bien así. Ya que al querer mostrar la información en la operación 3 no sé cómo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en definir tu variable `o` dentro del `scope` de primer caso.

Se trata de definir la variable `o` fuera, para que tenga sentido en todo el entorno de la función.

Suponiendo este `struct`

```
struct Objeto 
{
    int data;
    Objeto() {
        // Hace algo
        cout << "Creating object\n";
    }
};
```

Definimos en la función de las operaciones el `switch-case`.

```
Objeto* o;
int op;
int n;

do {
    cout << "Enter operation... ";
    cin >> op;

    switch(op) {
        // Cases statements...
    }
} 
while (op != -1);
```

Declara de forma global un objeto de tipo `Objeto` fuera del `switch-case` para tener accesibilidad a ella en todo el `scope`.
Lo he hecho con un bucle, pero puedes impleementarlo como necesites.

En el mismo `switch`, definimos los `case` y un `default`

```
switch(op) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Define size... ";
        cin >> n;

        o = new Objeto[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            cout << "Enter data... ";
            cin >> o[i].data;   
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (n != 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                cout << "Data " << o[i].data << " in object " << i << "\n";      
            }
            break;
        }       
    default:
        cout << "Operation not permitted\n";
        break;
}
```

En la operación `1`, se pide el tamaño del `struct` y los datos a rellenar.
En la operación `2`, se tiene la misma referencia al objeto `o`, por lo que podemos leerlo y acceder a él.

> Como la variable `n` también está definida fuera del `scope` del `switch-case`, podemos aprovecharla en todos los `case`.
>   En mi caso, la uso para no permitir la operación `2` si es que no se ha realizado la operación `1` previamente (lo compruebo con el valor por defecto `0`, quizás sería mejor otorgar un valor por defecto diferente a la variable `n` como por ejemplo `-1` y comprobarlo con este, para que el valor `0` fuera permitido.
>   En caso que la operación `2` no se permita, salta a `default` e imprime el debido mensaje.

Dejo un fiddle con el código [aquí](http://cpp.sh/62tix).

Otra solución interesante sería separar cada uno de los `case` en una función y pasar por referencia el objeto `o` (o el punto a éste).

Answer (score 0):

> Estoy desarrollando un programa donde se requiere que el struct tenga n tamaño.

Es imposible que requiera eso porque no es algo que sea posible en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Un tipo de datos (por ejemplo una `struct` definida por el usuario) tiene un tamaño fijo imposible de variar. Es como si dijeras que estás construyendo un coche del que se requiere que tenga n ruedas y la cantidad de ruedas se decidirá después de construirlo.

Por lo que veo de tu código, lo que en realidad quieres es una colección de objetos cuyo tamaño sea definido por el usuario. Para ello puedes usar `std::vector` que tiene un constructor en que le puedes decir los elementos a almacenar:

```
int cantidad;
cout << "Digite la cantidad de libros que desea almacenar: ";
cin >> cantidad;

// Crear un vector de 'n' elementos.
std::vector<objetos> libros(n);

for (auto &l : libros)
{
    l.tipo = "Libro"; 

    cout<<"Digite el número de referencia del libro: ";
    getline(cin, l.num_ref);

    cout<<"Digite el título: ";
    getline(cin, l.titulo);

    cout<<"Digite el autor: ";
    getline(cin, l.autor);

    cout<<"Digite la editorial: ";
    getline(cin, l.editorial);

    cout<<"Digite el número de edición: ";
    getline(cin, l.num_edi);

    cout<<"Digite el año de publicación: ";
    getline(cin, l.annio);
}
```